# PHP Zip random files from directory

Tags: php, file, random, zip, directory

I am currently making a website and I am trying to collect a number of random files from a folder on my server (./uploads) and zip them so the user can download them. I think I am pretty close but cant seem to setup the loop right.  I am trying to first get 20 random files with the line `$files = $nfiles[array_rand($nfiles,20)];`  then take these 20 files and use the loop to zip them all up but I can not figure out quite how to do it. :/

edit: discovered that i need to use `$rand_indexes = array_rand($nfiles, 20);` instead..now to figure out how to replace the glob function to just get a list of all objects.

```
<?php 
$rootPath = realpath('./uploads');
//make zip file
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('file.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
$nfiles = glob($rootPath.'*.{aiff}', GLOB_BRACE);     
$files = $nfiles[array_rand($nfiles,20)]; 
//-------------------------------------------//
foreach ($files as $file)
 { 
 if (!$file->isDir())
{
    // Get path for current file
    $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
    $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);  
    // Add file to zip
    $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
}
 }
 //-------------------------------------------//
 $zip->close();
 header('Content-Type: application/zip');
 header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.'generated            
 sounds.zip');
 header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('file.zip'));
 readfile('file.zip');
  if(file_exists('file.zip')){
  unlink('file.zip');
 }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

As per the manual:

> When picking only one entry, array_rand() returns the key for a random entry. **Otherwise, an array of keys for the random entries is returned**.

As you are fetching `20` entries, `array_rand()`'s return value is an *array*. You therefore would need to do as such:

```
$files = array_rand($nfiles, 20);

foreach($files as $file) {

    $pathToFile = $nfiles[$file];

    // the rest of your code using $pathToFile

}
```

Comment: okay i did that but still get an odd error that says 503 backend fetch failed.     
  `$nfiles = glob($rootPath.'*.{aiff}', GLOB_BRACE);     
$files = array_rand($nfiles, 20);
foreach($files as $file) 
{
 if (!$file->isDir())
{
    // Get path for current file
    $pathtofile = $nfiles[$file]
    $filePath = $pathtofile->getRealPath(); `

Comment: You need to do `$pathtofile = $nfiles[$file]` right after `foreach($files as $file) {`.